# contain background size not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following html declared inside a render() function using Reactjs

```
 <div className={"companyImages"}>
    <div className={"thubm"} style={{background:'url(https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/character_mickeymouse_home_mickey_notemplate_3a0db1b2.jpeg?region=0,0,600,600&width=320)'}}></div>
</div>
```

and my CSS looks as below:

```
.companyImages div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:4px;
  width:51px;
  height:51px;
}

.companyImages .thubm {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Current state: only a small part of the image is shown.

Exptected: Whole image resized and fit the div.

Screenshot:

[image]

while you can look the image link and see whole image separately in new tab.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot, please?

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: Google Chrome I am using but it is the same with firefox as well

Comment: try: `.companyImages{height: 100%;}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The inline style overrides all your by CSS provided stylings. You have to specify it by `background-image`.

```css
.companyImages div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
}

.companyImages .thubm {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="companyImages">
  <div class="thubm" style="background-image: url(https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/character_mickeymouse_home_mickey_notemplate_3a0db1b2.jpeg?region=0,0,600,600&width=320)"> </div>
</div>
```

In your case the right react code would look like this:

```
<div className={"companyImages"}>
    <div className={"thubm"} style={{background-image:'url(https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/character_mickeymouse_home_mickey_notemplate_3a0db1b2.jpeg?region=0,0,600,600&width=320)'}}></div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

Your CSS styles include `background-size` and `background-repeat`, which will be overwritten by the inline style `background`.

**Further reading:**

> The property is a shorthand that sets the following properties in a single declaration: background-clip, background-color, background-image, background-origin, background-position, background-repeat, background-size, and background-attachment.
>
> [stephaniehobson](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/profiles/stephaniehobson), [mfuji09](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/profiles/mfuji09), [mfluehr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/profiles/mfluehr) et. al.: [**background - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.companyImages div {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 4px;
      width: 51px;
      height: 51px;
    }
    .thubm {
        background: url("https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/character_mickeymouse_home_mickey_notemplate_3a0db1b2.jpeg?region=0,0,600,600&width=320");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="companyImages">
      <div class="thubm"> </div>
    </div>
```